# How to import files/modules in python3 in windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I have program which needs to make use of 2 files to be sourced. This works in linux but not in windows:

[image]

I have then imported them as follows:

```
import random
from hangman_art import stages, logo
from hangman_words import word_list

print(logo)
```

Getting an error:

```
File "c:\Users\MANNY\Documents\python100\hangman\hangman_game.py", line 2, in <module>
    from hangman_art import stages, logo
ImportError: cannot import name 'stages' from 'hangman_art'
```

Code for hangman_art.py:

```
stages = ['''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 / \  |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 /    |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
      |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|   |
      |
      |
=========''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
  |   |
      |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
      |
      |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
      |
      |
      |
      |
=========
''']

logo = ''' 
 _                                             
| |                                            
| |__   __ _ _ __   __ _ _ __ ___   __ _ _ __  
| '_ \ / _` | '_ \ / _` | '_ ` _ \ / _` | '_ \ 
| | | | (_| | | | | (_| | | | | | | (_| | | | |
|_| |_|\__,_|_| |_|\__, |_| |_| |_|\__,_|_| |_|
                    __/ |                      
                   |___/    '''
```

Comment: does `hangman_art` contain this `stages`? could you please add this code part of `hangman_art.py`?

Comment: @dukkee updated with the code for `hangman_art`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in VS Code editor. I had to define the `pythonpath` to honor the modules.

```
{
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["./hangman"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in replace it with under code .

```
from . import hangman-words
```

and . or dot mean this directory or hangman directory.

read flask source code

Answer (score 0):

in replace it with under code .

```
from .hangman_art import stages, logo
from .hangman_words import word_list
```

. Indicates the current directory

For example, I import function1 from module2

directory structure:

```
project
    ├── package1
       ├── module1.py
       └── module2.py
```

example:

```
# package1/module1.py

from .module2 import function1
```

Comment: This would only work if the directory is a _package_, which is not at all apparent here.

Answer (score 0):

Press f5 in vs code in your main.py file then select the environment to python.file and then hit run it wil[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4g3k.png)